# Migrating from Symfony 2.1 to 2.5, choice fields not working

Tags: symfony

I'm updating a Symfony 2.1 project to 2.5, and noticed the country and foreign entity dropdowns are empty.

This is the form:

```
namespace KF\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('lastName', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('required' => true))
            ->add('telephone', null, array('required' => false))
            ->add('country', 'country', array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'property_path' => 'addressHome.country',
                        'empty_value' => 'user.registration_form.select_country',
                        'empty_data' => null
                ))
            ->add('agency', 'entity', array(
                        'class' => 'KFEEEPBundle:Agency',
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'empty_value' => 'user.registration_form.select_agency',
                        'empty_data' => null,
                        'required' => true))
            ->add('motivation', 'textarea', array('attr' => array('cols' => 50, 'rows' => 8), 'required' => false))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'kf_userbundle_accountdetailstype';

    }
}
```

Country is a native Symfony form type, and should just work..the 'agency' class is found and the DB contains records, yet is also empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Country is new to 2.5.  How did your do the upgrade?  I'm thinking your composer.json might need to be replaced with the 2.5 version and then do a fresh install?  The icu stuff might be out of date.  Consider also making a simple test form with just country.

Comment: country was already there in the 2.1 version..the docs confirm this: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/types/country.html. I'll try a testform..

Comment: A new testbundle inside my project didn't work either..I created a fresh symfony install from scratch and my testbundle does work there..I'll slowy migrate my bundles and see if something breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my form was being overriden, and the `choice_widget` with it.

That, in turn, used this deprecated twig block `widget_choice_options` (instead of the new `choice_widget_options`).

This page describes it in detail:

https://medium.com/@sprain/updating-to-symfony-2-3-with-some-form-surprises-2e43b6be2b6d